# Override getter and setter for has_many through relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I have the following models:

```
class Doctor
   has_many :doctors_appointments
   has_many :appointments, through: :doctors_appointments
   ...

   def set_appointments(appointment_list=[])
       #logic to add appointments, including defaults when list is empty
       final_appointment_list.each do
           self.appointments.append(appointment)
       end
       self.save
   end

   def get_appointments(appointment_list=[])
       if self.appointments.blank?
           self.set_appointments
       end
       self.appointments
   end
end

class Appointment
   belongs_to :doctor
   ...
end

class DoctorsAppointment
   belongs_to :doctor
   belongs_to :appointment
   ...
end
```

I want to be able to call

```
doctor.appointments = [<appointments>]
```

and

```
doctor_appointments = doctor.appointments
```

and have my custom getters and setters executed. Specific to my problem is how I would call the super in the setter at self.appointments.append and in the getter self.appointments. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: the justification for overriding the default getters and setters is if I create a new doctor. Currently I have to call:

```
doctor = doctor.new(doctor_params)
doctor.set_appointments(appointement_params)
doctor.save
```

Obviously the abstraction of doctors and appointments is only for this question, but in the real use case I would like to be able to call

```
doctor = doctor.new(doctor_params)
doctor.save
```

where appointments is a key in doctor params, and have the set_appointments called on save.

Comment: what is error when you call `doctor.appointments = [<appointments>]`?

Comment: so far, it looks like everythings fine, don't see why you'd need to override the defaults relations

Comment: please see updated question